# Difference of safety-critical SW development

Tags: standards, safety-critical

When developing safety-critical software using some quality standards (like e.g. IEC 61508 or DO 178-C) developers have to care about many things. I know that the verification in each development step is quite time consuming and expensive. Moreover, I know that some reduced programming languages are used.

But I am interested in the concrete difference to a "normal" SW-development process. I mean in the standard V-Model, verification and testing should also be part of each development step. What do I have to consider finding requirements? What do I have to consider in SW design?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't so much as a change in the "V Model" that helps verify critical system, it's what you do at each step of the way.

For example you may prefer to plan your development using waterfall in order to have verification steps and controlled transition periods. This has the benefit of staying in line with any government regulations that may be in place.

While developing it is common to use a limited subset of assemblies (APIs) in order to prevent developers from preforming dangerous operations. This type of restriction can also ensure that developers utilize the APIs correctly, such as cleaning up objects as a requirement.

Once the product has been developed you'll likely have gone through all of the testing phases. It is common in industry to develop test fixtures in order to verify and generate data to prove to the government or customers that your system says what it does.

In general, this topic is very deep. You did mention standards, one more is the ISO 2008 standard. I think what you should keep in mind is that the process doesn't change much (the life cycle model stays generally the same). But what you do at each step of the model will change depending on the project. You can take classes on Project Management... In fact it is a tract and sometimes a full degree program. So there's tons to learn about process and how to manage different projects.

Googling system critical projects and project management will likely generate a trove of knowledge.

Hope that helps shed some like on the subject.

EDIT: Finding requirements, like in a waterfall process, is very time consuming. It will involve understanding the customers needs and goals of course. In general you have to spend lots of time in this area for government reasons and software architecture. It's not really a different technique... Be explicit, understanding the requirements is most critical. The system shall recover from 90 second timeouts within 5 seconds of resetting. <- its like all other requirements in SW engineering... Explicit and testable. Objective not subjective. Think Grammer Nazi level of consideration.

One example of a safety critical systems is lockheeds F-35... The system requirements manuals are huge and the process to make a change requires meetings and quite a bit of paperwork.